# I don't know why I can't use asfreq()?

Tags: python, pandas

```
input_number=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\champion\Desktop\data_science_race\104.1~106.1\input_output\input\input_number.csv'
                         ,thousands=',',encoding='big5')
dates=pd.DatetimeIndex(input_number['date'])
input_number.index=dates
business_day=input_number.resample('B').asfreq()
```

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

This is my data.

[image]

I don't understand why I can't use `asfreq`. Because I use another similar data successfully executed.

Comment: Could you please show the data you are using (a limited example).

Comment: we need to be able to run the example. since we don't have your file, what you added doesn't help us much. use `StringIO` object to mock the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not using resample properly.

if you want to change frequency just use .asfreq such has:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

ts.asfreq('B')
Out[25]: 
2011-01-03    0.518565
2011-01-04    0.104616
2011-01-05    0.030174
2011-01-06    0.623529
2011-01-07    0.329330
2011-01-10   -0.012481
2011-01-11    1.119546
2011-01-12   -0.831261
2011-01-13   -0.137491
```

resample is something else, it resample your data and you can apply a function on that resample. so you could resample weekly and check the last value of that week:

```
ts.resample('W').last()
Out[26]: 
2011-01-02    0.401549
2011-01-09    0.800291
2011-01-16    0.843909
2011-01-23   -0.022525
2011-01-30   -0.225117
2011-02-06    0.338157
2011-02-13   -0.570128
2011-02-20    0.213254
2011-02-27    0.130544
2011-03-06   -1.652924
20

11-03-13    0.220274
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: float64
```